# RenderBox was not laid out : The relevant error-causing widget was ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, expandablelistview, expansion

I created an `ExpansionTile` widget and on expanding it display a search textfield and list of book using `ListView.Builder`, but it sending me this error

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6b9d7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1929 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ExpansionTile
```

here is the code

```
 return SafeArea(
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            color: Color(int.parse(bodycolor)),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(children: [
ExpansionTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.info_rounded,
                      color: HexColor("#5344ed")),
                  title: Text(
                    "Select Staff",
                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: HexColor("#5344ed")),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    buildSearch(),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: books.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final book = books[index];
                        
                        return ListTile(
                        
                          title: Text(book.title),
                          subtitle: Text(book.author),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ]),
  ])),
              ),
```

Update:

I edit my code, it result this ouput.

[image]

please help if anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you

Your List ->

```
List<String> data = [
    "Counter No 1",
    "Counter No 2",
    "Counter No 3",
    "Counter No 4",
  ];
```

Your Widget->

```
SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
          children: [
            // your other widget
            buildSearch(), 
            ExpansionTile(
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.info_rounded,
              ),
              title: Text(
                "Select Staff",
              ),
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(data[index]),
                      subtitle: Text('Your Data'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
       ),
```

Your result  screen before tap and other widget-> [image]

Your result  screen after tap-> [image]

You also refer my answer here for [ExpansionPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69460263/13997210)

Comment: i edit my question, uploaded the output of your code and update the code too, please check where i am doing wrong

Comment: Just add your Column widget inside `SingleChildScrollView()` check my updated answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your SafeArea in a `Material` widget

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `SafeArea` in a `Material` widget