# How do you create this sort of expandable DropDownButton? or menu?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout, expandablelistview

I wanted to make this sort of menu which expands when clicking. I tried to make it using DropDownMenu Button but I am just a beginner to learn flutter and couldn't make it. Please help.

This is what I want to archive:
[image]

Comment: Try my answer for `ExpansionPanel` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69460263/13997210) and `ExpansionTile`  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69462496/13997210)  hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this package to achieve your view
https://pub.dev/packages/expandable

[image: please look at these images]