# How to create a show more section for list tile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list tile and it initially looks like this:

[image]

What I want is that when I click on it, it expands and show more information like below:

[image]

So is there any widget for this or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: You can expand it manually using `setState`

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69462496/13997210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `ExpansionTile` which natively supported by flutter, [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yea You can achieve this by using package [Expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) widget Try this you will get your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Expanded Group is something that can help you easily:
https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_group

```
-> Use expansion Tile
ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('ExpansionTile 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Trailing expansion arrow icon'),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
          ],
        ),

->Create ListView with Divider
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: count,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('$index Title'),
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Column(children:[]);
  },
 )
```