# Expandable List in Flutter with animation controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to create an animated Expandable List in Flutter, such that whenever the user taps on a list item, it expands and starts showing the subtree of the component clicked. Meanwhile the main list items, through the animation, move up if they are before the clicked item, and down if they below the clicked item, until the end of the transition, when we can **ONLY** see the subtree of the clicked item and all the main list items are not shown anymore. You can grasp an idea from the steps below.

```
Normal View:          On item click (**):           After Clicking

------                ------ (Go up )               Shows only the subtree
------                ------ (Go up)                
------                **-----** (Expands)           
------                  -> Starts showing 
                           subtree

                      ------ (Go down)
```

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69460263/13997210)  hope it's helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a list of expansiontiles.

```
ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return ExpansionTile(
          title: Text("List tile $i"),
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text("List tile $i.1"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("List tile $i.2"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("List tile $i.3"),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
      itemCount: 100,
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but yet this is not my objective. At the end I should see ONLY the clicked ListTile element in your case, without seeing the main list elements. If I click, for instance, List tile $i.2, $i.1 should go up the view until it is not visible anymore. And $i.2's subelement should be positioned at the top of the parent widget. The same for $i.3, should go down until it is not visible anymore.